# stored procedure that synchronizes writeback table to a fact table, throws an error subquery returns more than one query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have stored a procedure that loads data from the writeback table to the fact table. If a user alters only a single row in excel and publishes the write back then the stored procedure synchronizes the writeback table to the fact table properly but if the users alter multiple rows then my stored procedure throws an error saying. subquery returned more than one value. this is not permitted when subquery follows =,!=,<,> or when the subquery is used as an expression. I don't know what to use other than subquery to update multiple rows.

This is the stored procedure;

```
Create PROC [dbo].[sp_load_purchase]
AS               
Merge          fact_purchase  target
using       ( 
        
SELECT      [ProductKey_6],[Vendor_5]
            ,year([Date_4]) [year_]
            ,month([Date_4]) [Month_]
            ,SUM([Purchased_x0024__1]) Purchased 
            ,sum([ReturnedQTY_2]) ReturnedQTY
            ,sum([Returned_x0024__3]) Returned
            ,sum([PurchasedQTY_0]) as PurchasedQTY  
FROM         [dbo].[WriteTable_Purchase]
GROUP BY     [ProductKey_6],[Vendor_5]
             ,year([Date_4]) 
             ,month([Date_4])       ) as Source 
ON          [Product]=[ProductKey_6]    
            and vendor=[Vendor_5]`          
            and year(target.[Date_key])=source.[year_]                
            and month(target.[Date_key])=source.[Month_]           
WHEN        MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET 
   target.[PurchasedQTY]=Case when source.[PurchasedQTY] is not null Then 
(SELECT         sum([PurchasedQTY_0])+ISNULL(PurchasedQTY,0) as
 FROM           [VR].[dbo].[WriteTable_Purchase]
                                   JOIN           [dbo].[Fact_Purchase] on [ProductKey_6]=product 
                                   WHERE          [Date]=@date
                                   GROUP BY       PurchasedQTY)
                                   else           target.[PurchasedQTY] end ,


            target.[Purchased$]= Case when source.Purchased is not null Then
                                  (SELECT         sum([Purchased_x0024__1])+ISNULL(Purchased$,0) as Purchased$
                                   FROM           [VR].[dbo].[WriteTable_Purchase]
                                   JOIN           [dbo].[Fact_Purchase] on [ProductKey_6]=product and [Vendor_5]=[Vendor]
                                   WHERE          [Date]=@date
                                   GROUP BY       Purchased$)
                                   else          target.[Purchased$] end,
           Target.[ReturnedQTY]= Case when source.ReturnedQTY  is not null then
                                  (SELECT         sum([ReturnedQTY_2])+ISNULL([ReturnedQTY],0) as [ReturnedQTY]
                                   FROM           [VR].[dbo].[WriteTable_Purchase]
                                   JOIN           [dbo].[Fact_Purchase] on [ProductKey_6]=product and [Vendor_5]=[Vendor]
                                   WHERE          [Date]=@date
                                   GROUP BY       [ReturnedQTY])
                                   else           target.[ReturnedQTY] end,
           Target.[Returned$]= case when source.Returned is not null then
                                  (SELECT         sum([Returned_x0024__3])+ISNULL([Returned$],0) as [Returned$]
                                   FROM           [VR].[dbo].[WriteTable_Purchase]
                                   JOIN           [dbo].[Fact_Purchase] on [ProductKey_6]=product and [Vendor_5]=[Vendor]
                                   WHERE          [Date]=@date
                                   GROUP BY       [Returned$] )
                                   else           target.Returned$ end
                                   ;
                              
TRUNCATE TABLE    [dbo].[WriteTable_Purchase]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the logic to create the dataset that will update the target in the "using" statement. Ensure that this only generates one record per key (the ON statement).

Then make the UPDATE statement a simple update of the values in your "using" dataset